# fatal: loose object?

Tags: php, git, nginx, laravel

После системной ошибки на хосте появилась такая ошибка.

```
Fatal error: unknown class App\Entry in /home/uzbek/uzbek.rf/www/app/Vacancy.php on line 25

error: inflate: data stream error (unknown comperssion method)
fatal: loose object 130dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba (stored in    .git/objects/13/0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba) is corrupt 

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Сайт выдает белый экран, что делать? Я так понимаю это проблема с git, но я с ним к сожедению на вы. :(

Comment: Вы используете гит? Если нет - то где эта ошибка?

Comment: ну ниже я ответила - у вас побились-потерялись файлы. Стряхивайте пыль с бэкапов :)

Comment: @Mira 
Спасибо большое, буду пытаться :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка у вас происходит при попытке программно разархивировать файл (`inflate` - это метод распаковки архива из `zlib`).

Ошибка поврежденного файла из репозитория гит так же имеется;

Вывод - у вас побились файлы. Надо восстанавливать и удалять все не подлежащее восстановлению;

Comment: Я правильно вас понял, нужно просто заменить файл 0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba? А есть полная инфа, где можно ознакомиться с процессом востановления?

Comment: 0dc6556560992b5a0f13992d5f0d716867c6ba - это не файл, а id побитого коммита. Как восстанавливать - зависит от окружения. Например, в gerrit даже при побитом коммите есть возможность вытащить более ранние его заливки. У вас там еще и битого архива ошибка - то есть думаю не один файл придется перезаливать, и универсального "как восстановить нет". Потому проще всего - расчехлить бэкап;

Comment: А можно откатить этот commit на предыдущий update, чтобы не трогать бэкап?

Comment: Я к сожалению не знакома с системой контроля версий которую вы указали (которая на основе гита), вы отдельным вопросом задайте "Как в системе Х восстановить битый коммит". В гите - геррите всегда есть локальный репозиторий и удаленный, потому можно перезалить туд и обратно. В вашей системе не знаю как :)

Comment: В моей системе есть локальный репозиторий на bitbucket, с локального сервера я push туда, а потом просто уже update на продакшен. Я вот и пытался в начале так же загрузить побитый класс от туда, но git начал выдовать ошибки :(

Comment: То есть вы загружаете с локального - а он не дает этого сделать, а вообще вы удаленный репозиторий можете просматривать (или совсем все лежит)?

Comment: Я свободно могу попасть на удаленный репозиторий и также отпушить данный на него с локального сервера, но уже загружить на продакшен с репозитория не получается выдает те ошибки, которые висят выше :( Как то так :(

Comment: Этот ваш последний комментарий очень хорошо формулирует проблему! Из первоначального вопроса не понятно что и где не работает. Задайте его в новой формулировке отдельным вопросом, больше людей сможет вам помочь! Здесь это уже выходит за рамки формата комментариев :)